# Different images for each FlowListView cell

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a FlowListView and I want to put different images from the default for each cell of my FlowListView, but I want to put it through a if condition, and the if condition requires the Text property of my button. I tried to do it in my ViewModel and xaml.cs file but in ViewModel I don't know how to get the Text property of the buttons and in my xaml.cs file I dont know how to do it in constructor.

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuUhh.png)

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSk75.png)

Xaml code:

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="true" FlowColumnExpand="ProportionalLast"
                    FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
                    FlowItemsSource="{Binding MyCategories}" >
            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Image="carne.png"
                                Command="{Binding IdCatalogs}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                TextColor="White"     
                                Clicked="ButtonSelected"                               
                                ContentLayout="Top"
                                BackgroundColor="#40000000"
                                BorderColor="#FFFFFF"
                                BorderWidth="2"
                                CornerRadius="6">
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</flv:FlowListView>
```

Xaml.cs file code:

```
public partial class CategoriesMenuDetail : ContentPage
    {
        public Dictionary<int, Btn> buttons { get; set; }

        public CategoriesMenuDetail()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buttons = new Dictionary<int, Btn>();
        }

        public void ButtonSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            var button = (Button)sender;

            if (!buttons.ContainsKey(button.GetHashCode()))
            {
                buttons.Add(button.GetHashCode(), new Btn(button));
            }

            bool state = buttons[button.GetHashCode()].Toogle();

            if (button.Text == "Carnes")
            {
                var image = (state) ? "carneslc.png" : "carne.png";

                button.Image = image;
            }
            if (button.Text == "Peixes")
            {
                var image = (state) ? "peixeslc.png" : "peixe.png";

                button.Image = image;
            }
            if (button.Text == "Entradas")
            {
                var image = (state) ? "entradaslc.png" : "entrada.png";

                button.Image = image;
            }

            var bgColor = (state) ? Color.FromHex("#26047AD5") : Color.FromHex("#40000000");
            var borderColor = (state) ? Color.FromHex("#FF8A00") : Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF");

            button.BackgroundColor = bgColor;
            button.BorderColor = borderColor;
        }
    }

    public  class Btn
    {
        private Button _button { get; set; }

        private bool isToogle = false;

        public Btn(Button button)
        {
            _button = button;
        }

        public bool Toogle()
        {
            isToogle = !isToogle;
            return isToogle;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel code:

```
 private RestaurantsClient restaurantsClient { get; set; }

        private ObservableCollection<CategoryDetail> _myCategories;
        public ObservableCollection<CategoryDetail> MyCategories
        {
            set
            {
                _myCategories = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MyCategories));
            }
            get
            {
                return _myCategories;
            }
        }

        public RestaurantsReaderViewModel()
        {

            restaurantsClient = (App.Current as App).restaurantsClient;

            var restaurantsNames = restaurantsClient.GetCategoriesAsync(2).Result;
            MyCategories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryDetail>(restaurantsNames.Categories);
        }
```

CategoryDetailModel:

```
public partial class CategoryDetail
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("name", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ToJson()
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }

        public static CategoryDetail FromJson(string data)
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CategoryDetail>(data);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are setting image button as static in xaml Image="carne.png", for get dynamic image you need to bind those image

Comment: @Prasanth Yes I know it, but I dont know how to do it, if I bind for the ViewModel I dont know how to get Text property to do the if condition, if I bind for the xaml.cs file I dont know how to do it in the constructor, because the Text property is in object sender.

Comment: Basically what you want is based on some conditions the images should be dynamic right?

Comment: @Prasanth this code was taken with NSwagStudio from my API. I will put the code in question.

Comment: in your CategoryDetail contain only Name variable, you need to create a Model with Name and ImageName object and bind again. Can you shour CategoryDetail Model

Comment: In the 'CategoryDetailModel' you have only Id and Name, for dynamically binding you need to have  image property also as well as in 'CategoryDetail' class

Comment: @Prasanth But to do that I need to change my Database and many other things, isnt there any other solution?

Comment: Sorry! as per my experience no way to do using dynamically

Comment: @Prasanth Ok, if I change my ViewModel how can I change the images in my xaml.cs file. Im talking about the ifs statments in xaml.cs code.

Comment: @Prasanth Problem solved, thank you for take some of your time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tackle this in a couple of different ways:

1. You can create a ValueConverter which converts your Id or Name on the CategoryDetail to the image path and bind that to the `Image` property.
2. Add the image as a property in the CategoryDetail and bind directly

For the ValueConveter approach you need to implement the `IValueConveter` interface, it could look something like this:

```
public class CategoryImageValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var name = (string)value;

        switch (name)
        {
            case "Entradas":
                return "entradas.png";
            case "Carnes":
                return "carnes.png";
            case "Peixes":
                return "peixes.png";

            // add more here
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you need to tell Xamarin.Forms where to look for this ValueConverter. So on the Page add:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:CategoryImageValueConverter x:Key="categoryImage" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Now you can change your binding for the `Image` property to:

```
Image="{Binding Name, Converter{StaticResource categoryImage}}"
```

As for the other solution where you put it directly into the CategoryDetail class, you simply create a new property and populate these items with the correct image name and bind that property. For the example lets call it `ImageName`:

```
Image="{Binding ImageName}"
```

And it would look something like this in CategoryDetail:

```
private string _imageName;
public string ImageName
{
    get => _imageName;
    set
    {
        _imageName = value;
    }
}
```

If your CategoryDetail class implements INotifyPropertyChanged remember to fire the PropertyChanged event too if you set the image names later.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked very well. Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 0):

You buttons Command is binded to IdCatalog, probably it's a numeric value, it shoul be a ICommand proerty and you VM should looks like:

```
public ICommand MyButtonCommand => new Command( (param) =>{ ... });
//Param is CommandParameter value, you should cast before use it
```

If you want to use UI's event, first you Image property must be binded from your VM and set as notificable property.

If you changes the image as your code, UI is not notified that values has changed.

EDITED:

Your code with a good structure should be like this

```
public partial class CategoriesMenuDetail : ContentPage
{
    public CategoriesMenuDetailViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public CategoriesMenuDetail()
    {
        ViewModel = new CategoriesMenuDetailViewModel();

        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = Viewmodel;

    }
}


public class CategoriesMenuDetailViewModel 
{
    public List<CategoryDetail>MyCategories { get; set; } // if you don't add new items not need observable collection

    public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand => new Command((cParameter)=> ButtonclickedCommandExecute((CategoryDetail)cParameter)


    private void ButtonclickedCommandExecute(CategoryDetail myParam)
    {
        //Here goes you image's logic
        if (myParam.Name == "Carnes")
            myParam.ImageName = Image.FromFile("");
    }

}

public class CategoryDetail : ObservableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string _name;
    public string Name { get =>_name; set=>SetProperty(ref _name, value); }

    private string _imageName;
    public string  ImageName { get=>_imageName; set=>SetProperty(ref _imageName, value); }
}


public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "", Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

And XAML

```
 <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount = "3" SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="true" FlowColumnExpand="ProportionalLast"
                    FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
                    FlowItemsSource="{Binding MyCategories}" >
            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Text = "{Binding Name}"
                                Image="{Binding ImageName}"
                                Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                TextColor="White"     
                                Clicked="ButtonSelected"                               
                                ContentLayout="Top"
                                BackgroundColor="#40000000"
                                BorderColor="#FFFFFF"
                                BorderWidth="2"
                                CornerRadius="6">
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</flv:FlowListView>
```

Comment: The problem isnt the UI's event or binds, is the if condition, I need to do a if condition with Button.Text property and I dont know how to get it in ViewModel and in the constructor of xaml.cs file.

Comment: I edited the post, you are not using correctly events and commands

Comment: I cant edit CategoryDetail cause its a NSwagStudio code of my API.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you for take some of your time to help me.

Comment: I already tried but:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.